# Encoding type of display_name

Tags: discussion, users, api-v2.2

I am using the v2.2 api. There is a small issue I have come across.

For the `display_name` I do not understand the encoding. For example for this [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/562459/mike-sherrill-cat-recall), the name comes as `Mike Sherrill &#39;Cat Recall&#39;`

Appears to me as [URL encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). Is there any link which specifies the arguments I should be expecting for different parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not URL encoding, that is [HTML entity encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references).

By default, the API returns "safe" values; **see [the *filters* doc](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters)**:

> Any string returned as a result of an API call with a safe filter will be inline-able into HTML without script-injection concerns. That is to say, no additional sanitizing (encoding, HTML tag stripping, etc.) will be necessary on returned strings.

That means that special characters (`<>'"&`, etc.) will be HTML entity encoded by default.

If you [run the same query with an **"unsafe" filter**](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users-by-ids#order=desc&sort=reputation&ids=562459&filter=vqc7z&site=stackoverflow&run=true) (See [the doc](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters)), you can often get the raw values:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      ...
      "user_id": 562459,
      ...
      "display_name": "Mike Sherrill 'Cat Recall'",
      ...
```